# Default language via settings not respected during testing

Tags: django, testing, internationalization

Using Django 1.3, Python 2.6

Having a particularly weird problem to track down related to 
internationalization, and RequestFactory vs. TestClient for testing 
views.

If I run:

```
./manage.py test
```

All tests run (including the problematic ones) and pass successfully.  If I run:

```
./manage.py test <appname>
```

The app's tests will fail, throwing a template rendering exception for 
templates that use the language code because the language django 
thinks the request is asking for is not a language we've listed in 
settings.LANGUAGES. (In this case it has always been 'en-us', the closet matching language we support being 'en')

Here's an example of a test that will fail:

```
class TemplateServingTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app_dir      = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
        self.gallery_root = os.path.join(self.app_dir, 'test_gallery')
        self.gallery_url  = '/'
        self.request      = RequestFactory().get('/')

    def test_404_invalid_category(self):
        self.assertRaises(Http404, gallery_page,
            self.request,
            'bad-category',
            self.gallery_root,
            self.gallery_url
        )
```

This problem will not occur if django's TestClient is used to make a 
request to a url that calls a particular view.  However if that same 
view is simply called with the result of RequestFactory's get or put 
methods, it will throw the error above.

It appears as though when using the RequestFactory method, the 
settings file is not being respected.  Am I missing something simple 
here?

## Additional Information

Applicable locale settings

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('de', 'Deutsch'),
    ('es', 'Espanol'),
    ('fr', 'Francaise'),
    ('it', 'Italiano'),
    ('pt-br', 'Portugues (Brasil)'),
)
```

Active middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'services.middleware.LegacyIntegrationMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 possibilities :

a) You have `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

In this case, the client use `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

b) You don't.

In that case, you should set the language like that somewhere in your tests.py module:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate
...
activate('fr-fr')
```

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15143

Comment: See edits above, a) is not working as expected in this case. b) Does solve the problem, but still really curious why RequestFactory doesn't honor the settings file.

Comment: Tested a) and works for me with same versions of Python and Django. Beware of middlewares ordering.

Comment: Your `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting looks invalid. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#language-code

Comment: @kaptainlange Somehow (a) does not seem to work for me either. Using `LocaleMiddleware` and `LANGUAGE_CODE='en-us'`, when I do `reverse('my_name')` I get `http://testserver/en-us/...` whereas it is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/...` in server. Additionaly, `client.get()` returns 404 with `reverse`, in contrast to using a static url with `/en/`.

Answer (score 0):

> However if that same view is simply called with the result of RequestFactory's get or put methods, it will throw the error above.

I imagine you are doing something like:

```
from django.utils import translation
from app.views import some_view

# Using translation.activate is pretty well known, so I suppose you
# also do this:
translation.activate(<whatever language you want>)

request_factory = RequestFactory()
request = request_factory.get("/foo")

response = some_view(request)
```

Then the URLs produced by the request have `None` instead of the language you wanted. You can try using a URL with a language prefix. You can try setting a language cookie in your request. You can try fiddling with the session. Nothing works.

The reason is does not work is because **you are bypassing the entire middleware machinery**. You are calling the view directly. Django won't intervene, take the request and pass it through the middlewares.

What you *can* do is call whatever middleware you need, or you can replicate what the middleware does. In order to get a request produced with `RequestFactory` to honor the language settings, I chose the latter and I did this:

```
translation.activate("en-us")
request.LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
response = some_view(request)
```

This was enough for me to get the language prefix added to my URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using [behave-django](https://behave-django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for testing purpouses. None of the above solutions work for me.

The right thing is calling:

```
settings.MIDDLEWARE.remove('django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')
```

in the fixture setup of the test. In particular for behave, in environment.py:

```
def before_all(context):
    context.browser = Browser('chrome', headless=True)
    # The LocaleMiddleware can false tests
    settings.MIDDLEWARE.remove('django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')
    # enforce english language for testing
    settings.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
```