# Django Request Factory with different languages

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using django-cms with 4 different languages. When i write this:

```
from django.test.client import RequestFactory

factory = RequestFactory() 
request = factory.get('some_url')
```

I get request with default language. How can i change language for request? Something like:

`request.language = 'en'`

Is it possible?

Comment: did you try factory.get('/language-code/some_url/')?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default language via settings not respected during testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673842/default-language-via-settings-not-respected-during-testing)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.get('some_url')
request.LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'
```

See https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/052f51691804a0882b0e436aad40d9c0e95ce181/cms/test_utils/testcases.py#L342